# How does Trine's lighting look so spectacular?

Tags: lighting, shadows

Is there some kind of "special" lighting in this scene? I notice that the sun seems to "pop".

[image: Trine]

Comment: Ugh. Why do people think this looks good? :(

Comment: Needs more brown.

Comment: @JonPurdy because to some of us it does.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs: I just think blurring the specular channel on *everything* is a bit excessive. It's like a lens flare: it's a simulation of the side-effects of an imperfect lens. Why would you do that?

Comment: @JonPurdy By no means am I saying it's a great effect and should be used everywhere. It's a tool, and it has its place. In the picture above, it makes everything hazy and golden and almost dreamlike. Some parts of it really didn't need to be ramped up (like the rocks), and it may not have been appropriate even in that situation, but it isn't an awful effect across the board.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs: That's fair. I just find it a particularly overused tool. Things have a tendency of being overused when they become easy to use, then tone down over time (consider the early internet). I think that's what's happening with bloom.

Comment: Looks to me like they may have artificially adjusted the contrast too. The foreground looks high contrast and the background low contrast.

Comment: Yes, the bloom effect simulates lens imperfection. However like Jonathan mentioned this produces a convincing "dreamlike" quality in the image which tends to be attractive (not for everybody) because of that surreal quality. I think it can also help make lighting look more realistic in a slightly nonphysical way: anything near a bright object will have light "spilled" on to it, as if it were lit by it, though it is a screen space effect only. Conversely anything bright will automatically gain a halo that conforms to its shape. When the effect is used judiciously, it can look very realistic.

Comment: +1 to Jon Purdy. I absolutely cannot stand this golden-brown over-bloomed style. Bloom is the worst thing to hit videogame graphics since the lens flare. It masks details and makes it difficult to take a scene seriously. Take the wall on the right. There's no way the light reflecting off of it is strong enough to cause actual bloom, but there it is. It looks incredibly artificial.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It uses a [bloom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_%28shader_effect%29) shader. That's a post-processing effect that makes bright areas of the rendering appear to glow.

Comment: +1, however, calling it a bloom filter is potentially misleading as this effect has nothing to do with 'bloom filters' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Probably better to just call it a bloom effect.

Comment: good point, edited.

Comment: @DantheMan If you really want to thank him, mark this as the answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I know.